# Unable to UEFI boot once RAID is enabled

Tags: boot, windows-10, raid, uefi

I have the current drive setup. 1 SSD that holds windows, 2 smaller SSD's that are RAID0'd and 1 platter drive.

When I installed windows 10, all was good and things were booting fine. After a BIOS problem I reset my settings which included disabling RAID on my board. The system booted fine but I was unable to see my RAID0.

After enabled RAID0 again in my BIOS, I'm unable to boot (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE) after booting from a usb and running diskpart to take a look. The RAID0 drive now wants to be drive `C`.

I've tried assigning the proper drive letters in diskpart and things just get reset when I restart.

Can someone help me understand how booting is working? I know the BIOS and boot phase has no concept of drive letters so I assume the UEFI startup phase is assigning those? How can I force my RAID0 drive back to drive letter `D` and my boot drive to `C`?

Comment: Drive letters aren't a UEFI thing either: they're entirely a Windows thing, and drive letter assignments can differ between different copes of Windows on the same computer.  INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE is an error message from the Windows bootloader, which means you've gotten through the UEFI stuff (whose job is to load the OS bootloader).  This sounds like a problem with the Windows boot configuration, and may not be related to UEFI at all.

Comment: Does anyone know the steps to trouble shoot this? The problem goes away when I disable RAID so I imagine is something to do with that drive hijacking things but there's not a lot of logging/info on to whats going on

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is newer motherboards will add a disk item to the boot order just because it sees some new disk at post, which does not help keeping things sorted as to what boot order is.  Lettering a disk C might indicate system thinks it is the boot disk. I always limit the boot to 1 item (disable everything else).
 Then drivering the disk controller in windows (general) is not always  compatable between raid/ahci/compatable/Ide modes and can crash, but not that error that I know of.   
It really helps to have worked out the whole layout first, especially with raid.